# Create a border around <div class="loader">

Tags: html, css, border

My previous attempt by creating a border around the body was just fine, but after wanting to create a border rotating animation I am forced to create a div around all my contents, but the problem is whenever I try to create a border around that div, it simply doesn't show.

```css
@use postcss-preset-env;
@use postcss-nested;
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

.loader {
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">

  <div class="content">
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="toggleMute()">Mute</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var muted = video.getAttribute("muted");

    function toggleMute() {
      if (muted) {
        video.removeAttribute("muted");
        btn.innerHTML = "Mute";
      } else {
        video.setAttribute("muted");
        btn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
      }
    }
  </script>


  <div class="outer-box-frame">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="video">
        <source src="video/videoplayback.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually after and what's your actual issue... could you please rephrase your question? *rotating animation*? ...?

Comment: Sorry for my inability to properly describe my problem. I just need to create a border around all of my contents(<div class="loader">), but for some reason the code i wrote for the border doesnt seem to work. My question is, where have I made a mistake and how could it be fixed?

Comment: your code shows that white border Can you clarify your issue , if needed , share the all code that **demonstrate** your issue  Welcome on SO

Answer (score 0):

You are using border color white at line.

**CSS:**

`border: 5px solid white;`

Use another color than white, your background is white.

`border: 5px solid red; //red for example`

Or try the developer mode of your browser. (right click > inspect in Chrome)

Answer (score -1):

@Damian Zykovic, there seems to be a border of width 5px, since the color is white i think you are not able to see the border.

Just for Testing: Change the color of the border to something visible like red you will be able to see the border just for your verification.

Below is your code, You will be able to see the border

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="loader">

        <div class="content">
            <button id="myBtn" onclick="toggleMute()">Mute</button>
        </div>

        <style>
            @use postcss-preset-env;
            @use postcss-nested;

            html,
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
            }

            .loader {
                border: 5px solid red;
                display: block;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-width: 5px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="outer-box-frame">
            <video autoplay muted loop id="video">
                <source src="video/videoplayback.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Use `red` instead of `white`" ?? Are you sure OP really missed that one? Also, please  notice OP already closed properly the *loader* `</div>`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have edited my answer please look at it again, also I don't think `loader` div is closed, please check again...

Comment: Please, see `</div></body>` - ? Does the `</div>` closes the loader? The Q markup is just not well formatted. But it's closed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan okey i was wrong, i will remove that

Comment: Background is mostly black, thats the reason why i chose a white border. I already have tried different color combinations, but none of them seem to work. Div loader is closed, its just above the </body> tag.

Comment: Also @AbhinavaBN why do you use `border-style: solid;` ? Is there anything wrong with `solid` in `border: 5px solid red;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan both do the same thing... removed the redundant code